# Saving Image with PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to save an image that I created from scratch with PIL

```
newImg1 = PIL.Image.new('RGB', (512,512))
pixels1 = newImg1.load()

...

for i in range (0,511):
    for j in range (0,511):
       ...
            pixels1[i, 511-j]=(0,0,0)
        ...

newImg1.PIL.save("img1.png")
```

and I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 523, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)   File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\xy\pyimgmake.py", line 125, in 
>       newImg1.PIL.save("img1.png")   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 512, in **getattr**
>       raise AttributeError(name) AttributeError: PIL

I need help interpreting this error and how to save the image properly as "img1.png" (I am fine with the image being saved to the default save spot).

---

UPDATE:

```
from PIL import Image as pimg
...
newImg1 = pimg.new('RGB', (512,512))
...
newImg1.save("img1.png")
```

and I get the following error:

> ... newImg1.save("img1.png")   File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1439, in save
>       save_handler(self, fp, filename)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\PngImagePlugin.py", line 572, in
>   _save
>       ImageFile._save(im, _idat(fp, chunk), [("zip", (0,0)+im.size, 0, rawmode)])   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py",
>   line 481, in _save
>       e = Image._getencoder(im.mode, e, a, im.encoderconfig)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 399, in _getencoder
>       return apply(encoder, (mode,) + args + extra) TypeError: an integer is required

Comment: remove `PIL.` from `newImg1.PIL.save("img1.png")`, and try.

Comment: Downvoted for the creative usage of new API methods or trying something without having checked any documentation.

Comment: that was my final attempt... I have updated the post with the error that the above suggestion produces

Answer (score 76, accepted):

PIL isn't an attribute of newImg1 but newImg1 is an instance of PIL.Image so it has a save method, thus the following should work.

```
newImg1.save("img1.png","PNG")
```

Note that just calling a file .png doesn't make it one so you need to specify the file format as a second parameter.

try:

```
type(newImg1)
dir(newImg1)
```

and

```
help(newImg1.save)
```

Comment: Extended answer. Note that the parameter list for save varies with the format.

Comment: You still left in the `.PIL` in the `save` call that was causing the original error.

Comment: Darn thats what I get for editing under the influence of a general anaesthetic.

Comment: Thanks for the new answer. Time ran out though, so I actually just passed the PIL into a matplotlib function. For some reason, there was no trouble with saving it this way... I guess whatever works.

Comment: The [docs now state](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.save) that the format **is** determined from the filename, so `newImg1.save('img1.png')` should work now.

Answer (score 6):

As I hate to see questions without a complete answer:

```
from PIL import Image
newImg1 = Image.new('RGB', (512,512))
for i in range (0,511):
    for j in range (0,511):
        newImg1.putpixel((i,j),(i+j%256,i,j))
newImg1.save("img1.png")
```

which yields a test pattern.

To use array style addressing on the image instead of putpixel, convert to a numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
pixels = np.asarray(newImg1)
pixels.shape, pixels.dtype
-> (512, 512, 3), dtype('uint8')
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
newImg1 = pimg.as_PIL('RGB', (512,512))
...
newImg1.save('Img1.png')
```